# i need assistance with a code i cannot get to run in javascript (closed)

Tags: javascript

here it is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<hl>Change an HTML element</hl>

<p id="msg">Now you see me.</p>

<button type="button"
onclick="document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = 'Gone!'">
Click Me!</button>

<button type="button"
onclick="document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = 'Back again!'">
Bring me back!</button>

</body>
</html>
```

does anyone recommend a way to fix this, because I am stumped.

Comment: it seems to be ok.

Comment: I get a 'syntax error' when I run it, trying to run on codecademy labs if that helps?

Comment: there is no error: https://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/umv8mu90/

Comment: I think it is just codecademy then; thanks for the help. =)

Comment: are you sure, that the second button should not restore the **old content**?

Comment: sorry for the trouble this post has assumingly caused, I am fairly new to this and learning for gcse's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though we should create the javascript file separately in real projects. But you can try the following code to test the stuff what you are trying to do/test.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<hl>Change an HTML element</hl>

<p id="msg">Now you see me.</p>

<button type="button" id="clickMeButton" onClick = clickMeClicked()>
Click Me!</button>

<button type="button" id="backMeButton" onClick = backMeClicked()>
Bring me back!</button>


<script>
function clickMeClicked() {
document.getElementById("clickMeButton").innerHTML = 'Gone!';
}
function backMeClicked() {
document.getElementById("backMeButton").innerHTML = 'Back again!';
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```